# Ina triangle $BFC$, show that $|KF|=b$ when $a>b$

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, triangles

Today I've encountered a question like this;

In a triangle $BFC$ angles $<B=20^\circ,\quad <F=110^\circ,\quad <C=50^\circ$,

There are points $D$(on BC) $\text{and}$ $K$(on BF) such that $|BD|=|BK|=a+b$ and $|DC|=a$, assuming $a>b$. How do we show that $|KF|=b$?,

This question is more abstract than the questions I generally deal with , although I've given it a try and my efforts are;

Creating a point $G$ such that points $D,K,G$ are linear (1)

Drawing a line from $B$ to $G$ and notice that $<GKB=30^\circ$ (2)

Seeing that $|GD|=a+b$ too (3)

Having discovered $<BGK=50^\circ$ drawing a line from $G$to $F$ (4)

Trying to find  $<KGF$ then expect to use the cosine theorem or perhaps another relation (This is where I am stuck),

I've begun this attempt of a solution with expectations like drawing the replica's or symmetric's of several parts in the triangle or finding a trigonometric relation, but I failed.

What do you suggest?

Comment: I think the question does not have enough information. Imagine moving the line KD, in a parallel way, closer and closer to B. Then BD = a+b becomes smaller and DC = a becomes larger which implies b becomes smaller. However KF = b is also becoming larger which is impossible.

Comment: I also thought there is something fishy about this question. Thank you:))

Comment: I draw with Geogebra and the conclusion is false because $KF$ depends on $a$ . Unless the request is to find $\dfrac{a}{b}$ such that $KF=b$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The property is false.

**A counterexample**.-If $(a,b)=(2,1)$ then $\overline{BD}=\overline{BK}=3$ and
$\overline{BC}=3+2=5$. Therefore if $\overline{KF}=b=1$ then $\overline{BF}=4$.

But then (keeping in mind that $\sin 110^{\circ}=\sin 20^{\circ}$)

$$\frac{4}{\sin 50^{\circ}}=\frac{5}{\sin 20^{\circ}}$$
This is not true.